# Resolve IP address of a Hostname using Excel / VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to retrieve the IP address of a Hostname, preferably using as few dependencies as possible. If possible no API calls and no external applications but if it's the only way, then so be it.

Example use:

```
Function IPfromHostname(myhostname as string)

  ' Validate myhostname is a valid domain format ?

  ' Query local dns server to resolve the IP address of myhostname

  'return the IP in decimal format

End Function
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's code that should work for you:

```
Function GetIPfromHostName(p_sHostName)
    Dim wmiQuery
    Dim objWMIService
    Dim objPing
    Dim objStatus

    wmiQuery = "Select * From Win32_PingStatus Where Address = '" & p_sHostName & "'"

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set objPing = objWMIService.ExecQuery(wmiQuery)

    For Each objStatus In objPing
        If objStatus.StatusCode = 0 Then
            GetIPfromHostName = objStatus.ProtocolAddress
        Else
            GetIPfromHostName = "Unreachable"
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you this works, example print GetIPfromHostName("www.slashdot.org") returns "216.105.38.15" . However sometimes it returns the IPV6 address instead for instance ("www.google.com") returns "2607:f8b0:400b:800::2004". It works for my purpose in any case !

Comment: OK, happy it works for what you are doing. When you use ping from a command prompt, are you getting an IPv6 address for www.google.com? Also, please mark the answer as accepted when you get a chance.

Comment: Hello, my organisation has blocked some or all icmp traffic, so now this always return unreachable. But the computer can still resolve dns if I type ping www.google.com, I can see the IP address, there's just no ping replies.   Is there still a way to resolve dns to ip without using ICMP pings ? thanks !

Comment: NOTE : I used this in the mean time, works great but it's huge https://blog.protocolsyntax.com/2014/01/17/followup-dns-lookup-and-ping-in-excel/

Comment: Please post a new question since it is a different problem